# CSS page-break-after does not work in Chrome

Tags: html, css

Below is my HTML file and CSS file

```css
.pageBreak {
  display: none;
}

@media print {
  #mainTable thead {
    display: table-header-group;
  }
  .accounts {
    page-break-after: always;
  }
}


/* For Chrome */

@media print and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
  .accounts {
    page-break-after: avoid;
  }
  .pageBreak {
    page-break-before: always;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print2.css">
</head>

<body>
  <table id="mainTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Header</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="accounts">
        <td>abc
          <h1 class="pageBreak"></h1>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="accounts">
        <td>def
          <h1 class="pageBreak"></h1>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="accounts">
        <td>ghi
          <h1 class="pageBreak"></h1>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="accounts">
        <td>klm
          <h1 class="pageBreak"></h1>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

I am not able to split the accounts in multiple pages.  I finally got above hack to work in Chrome but now it's creating extra page after each "accounts" row.  Any way to hide the extra page?   Also, not sure how this would behave with large amount of data.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?  print each row on a separate page?